# How to find the Cartesian equation of a plane curve from a parametric equation?

Tags: parametric, curves, substitution

More specifically, how to express

$$\begin{aligned}x(t) &=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
y(t) &=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\end{aligned}$$

in terms of $x$ and $y$? I attempted adding the two, getting a square from the numerator and a few other methods, but running out of time.

EDIT: please don't work backwards, and try to show this as simple as possible. Overcomplication or overdefining equations may confuse me even more.

Comment: I feel like the "as simple as possible" part of your edit is directly adressed to me. I would like to emphasize that using the resultant is definitely the way to go, any oher method will involve guessing the result.

Comment: it may be, but the way I learnt it was through simple substitution by cancelling the 't'. It may be inadequate, but it is all that is required, any extra aspects of the equation are unneccessary and useless to me, since I  am only a high school student and the concepts taught are at a much lower level.

Comment: but still, thanks for the edit

Comment: You should have stated explicitly that you are in high school, my answer is indeed totaly inappropriate. However, Robert Z's answer gives some food for thoughts.

Comment: that was what the edit was for ofc

Answer (score 5):

Those are the parametric equations of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$. 
In fact
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{(2t)^2+(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{4t^2+1-2t^2+t^4}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{1+2t^2+t^4}{(1+t^2)^2}=1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let define the following polynomials: $$\begin{align}P_x(t)&:=xt^2-2t+x,\\Q_y(t)&:=(y+1)t^2+y-1.\end{align}$$
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the curve defined by the given parametric equations, notice that: $$(x,y)\in\mathcal{C}\Leftrightarrow\exists t\textrm{ s.t }P_x(t)=0=Q_y(t).$$
Furthermore, notice that if $(x,y)\neq (0,-1)$, $\deg(P_x)=2=\deg(Q_y)$. Therefore, one has: $$(x,y)\in\mathcal{C}\setminus\{(0,-1)\}\Leftrightarrow\textrm{Res}_{2,2}(P_x,Q_y)=0.$$
Where $\textrm{Res}_{2,2}(P_x,Q_y)$ is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) in degree $(2,2)$ of $P_x$ and $Q_y$, when computing it one gets: $$\textrm{Res}_{2,2}(P_x,Q_y)=4(x^2+y^2-1).$$
Whence, $\mathcal{C}\setminus\{(0,-1)\}$ is given by $4(x^2+y^2-1)=0$, that is $x^2+y^2=1.$ Finally, notice that $(0,-1)$ satisfies the same equation to conclude that: $$\mathcal{C}:x^2+y^2=1.$$

**Remark.** This method is universal to all unicursal plane curves, that is plane curves given by a rational parametrization.